# why is pd.crosstab not giving the expected output in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a 2dataframes, which I am calling as df1 and df2.

df1 has columns like KPI and context and it looks like this.

```
    KPI                                                 Context 
0   Does the company have a policy in place to man...   Anti-Bribery Policy\nBroadridge does not toler...   
1   Does the company have a supplier code of conduct?   Vendor Code of Conduct Our vendors play an imp...   
2   Does the company have a grievance/complaint ha...   If you ever have a question or wish to report ...   
3   Does the company have a human rights policy ?   Human Rights Statement of Commitment Broadridg...   
4   Does the company have a policies consistent wi...   Anti-Bribery Policy\nBroadridge does not toler...
```

df2 has a single column 'keyword'

df2:

```
Keyword
0   1.5 degree
1   1.5°
2   2 degree
3   2°
4   accident
```

I wanted to create another dataframe out of these two dataframe wherein if a particular value from 'Keyword' column of df2 is present in the 'Context' of df1 then simply write the count of it.

for which I have used `pd.crosstab()` however I suspect that its not giving me the expected output.

here's what I have tried so far.

```
new_df = df1.explode('Context')
new_df1 = df2.explode('Keyword')
new_df = pd.crosstab(new_df['KPI'], new_df1['Keyword'], values=new_df['Context'], aggfunc='count').reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
print(new_df.head())
```

the new_df looks like this.

```
   KPI                                                       1.5 degree  1.5°  \
0  Does the Supplier code of conduct cover one or...         NaN   NaN   
1  Does the companies have sites/operations locat...         NaN   NaN   
2  Does the company have a due diligence process ...         NaN   NaN   
3  Does the company have a grievance/complaint ha...         NaN   NaN   
4  Does the company have a grievance/complaint ha...         NaN   NaN   

   2 degree  2°          accident  
0       NaN NaN           NaN              
1       NaN NaN           NaN             
2       NaN NaN           NaN          
3       1.0 NaN           NaN              
4       NaN NaN           NaN
```

The expected output which I want is something like this.

```
0   KPI                                            1.5   degree 1.5°    2 degree    2°  accident
1   Does the company have a policy in place to man 44     2     3       5           9
```

what exactly am I missing? please let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is multiple problems - first `explode` working with splitted values, not with strings. Then for extract `Keyword` from `Context` need [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) and for [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) use columns in same DataFrame, not 2 different:

```
import re

pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(re.escape(x)) for x in df2['Keyword'])

df1['new'] = df1['Context'].str.findall(pat, flags=re.I)

new_df = df1.explode('new')
out = pd.crosstab(new_df['KPI'], new_df['new'])
```

Comment: thanks a lot for highlighting my mistakes and correcting them, got to learn a new thing. Thanks a lot jezrael, this works as expected.

Comment: jezrael, one observation which I have noticed is that, its creating multiple Keyword in the output, like for example 'CODE OF CONDUCT', 'CODE OF CONDUcT', 'CHILD LABOR', 'CHILD LABOUR'', why exactly is that happening? is that because of flags=re.I ?

Comment: @technophile_3 - it means there are 2 times in Context in one row, `re.I` means ignore cases - lower or upper case of strings

Comment: yep, knew about re.I, it was causing because of that only, removing that solved it!